# backbone.js can't fetch data from url?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I had this working the other day, I don't know what I did differently but I can't fetch the data to add into my collection. From tutorials and the docs this code should work right?

```
var Player = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var PlayersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: "data/players.json",
  model: Player
});

var playersCollection = new PlayersCollection();

playersCollection.fetch({
    success: function(players) {
      alert('success')
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('fail')
    }
});
```

I get the error with that, I am thinking I am missing something **VERY** easy. Maybe it is my JSON, here is a look at it.

```
[
    {
       "name": "JELLY Bryant",
       "team": "Ballaz",
       "team_id": "1",
       "number": "24",
    },
    {
       "name": "Lebron James",
       "team": "Miami Heat",
       "team_id": "2",
       "number": "6"
    },
    {
       "name": "Dwayne Wade",
       "team": "Miami Heat",
       "team_id": "2",
       "number": "3"
    },
    {
       "name": "Michael Beasley",
       "team": "Miami Heat",
       "team_id": "2",
       "number": "30"
    },
    {
       "name": "Carmelo Anthony",
       "team": "New York Knicks",
       "team_id": "3",
       "number": "15" 
    },
    {
       "name": "Ron Artest",
       "team": "New York Knicks",
       "team_id": "3",
       "number": "5" 
    },
    {
       "name": "Karl Malone",
       "team": "Los Angeles Lakers",
       "team_id": "1",
       "number": "33"
    },
    {
       "name": "Damion Lillard",
       "team": "Portland Trailblazers",
       "team_id": "4",
       "number": "3" 
    },
    {
       "name": "Westly Matthews",
       "team": "Portland Trailblazers",
       "team_id": "4",
       "number": "55" 
    },
    {
       "name": "Wilt Chamberlin",
       "team": "Los Angeles Lakers",
       "team_id": "1",
       "number": "17" 
    }
]
```

Inside the network tab (chrome dev tools) it does make a successful get on the json.

```
Request URL:http://localhost/FRESH/data/players.json
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
```

I have to be missing something here lol. I had some large code that was getting data from hard coded collection then when I switched to the url method it wasn't working so I stripped it to the bare basics, so it's obviously something ticky-tack I am missing.

**WOOOOOOW** I saw that I added an extra comma to the end of the first json model "JELLY Bryant" and that solved it, I didnt think that was such a big deal, I just noticed it now.

Comment: Try your JSON in http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Yeah I think we went over this before that helped me then I edited a model and accidentally added a comma to the end.. If this happens again Ill know what to do!!

Comment: Should I delete this, or may it be helpful to others in knowing that if there is an error fetching to check the json, and make sure there are no trailing commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server sends an invalid JSON : you have a dangling comma in the first object. Check http://json.org/ for what constitutes a valid JSON format and some online tools like http://jsonlint.com/ can give you a quick check.

Try

```
[
    {
       "name": "JELLY Bryant",
       "team": "Ballaz",
       "team_id": "1",
       "number": "24"
    }
]
```

Comment: I figured that out as soon as I posted this, but thanks for the answer and links. This will definitely ensure I don't make this mistake again.